# How do I migrate my iTunes library from a Mac to a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, itunes, mediamonkey

I have Windows 7, 64-bit.  I'd like to use MediaMonkey on my Windows box; but I don't want to lose all the ratings and albums I made in iTunes.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've just found [this blog post](http://juniorbird.com/archive/000599.html) on the subject. Don't be put off by the "why would you want to move from a Mac" comments.

There's even a [page on the Apple support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1329), but this method involves using your iPod as the transfer medium.